# How to complement the block of parent template?

Tags: django, templates

I have `first.html`:

```html
    {% block title %}
        hi there
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        blah-blah
    {% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
        bye
    {% endblock %}
```

and `second.html`.
How can I incude all `first.html` page to `second.html` and complement `content` block like this:

```html
hi there
blah-blah
this text is from second.html
bye
```

I've tryed

```html
{% extends "first.html" %}
this text is from second.html
```

(just nothing added) and

```html
{% extends "first.html" %}
{% block content %}
    this text is from second.html
{% endblock %}
```

(block `content` is overrided).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [**`{{ block.super }}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) here when you want to render the original content as well. For example:

```
{% extends 'first.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    this text is from second.html
{% endblock %}
```